# Align image to the center of another image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have multiple images that need to be aligned in a specific manner, the 2nd `imageview` has to be aligned to the centre of the first `imageview`. How can that be achieved?[image]

i have attached an image for the reference,

As of now what I am doing is keeping a hidden view at the centre of `obj1`,and aligning the top of `obj2` to that, but it doesn’t seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won't you just get the `paddingTop`  of obj3 and half of it will be the `paddingTop` or `marginTop` of obj1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` and set alignment for `ImageViews`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLeft"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewRight"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i dont want it aligned to the left and right of the screen, pls read the question properly

Comment: then calculate obj1 height, obj1 margin from top in parent container; set to obj2 margin from top = marginFromTopObj1 + (heightObj1 / 2)

Comment: i wanted to achieve it via xml, but i guess its a bit too complex, i'll try this out thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this yourself And i hope this will help you in getting the views as per your requirement-

Create activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rlBase"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFF000" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Create imagemiddle.xml

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/imageViewMiddle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

In the main activity -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

And -

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        RelativeLayout rlParent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlBase);
        int height = rlParent.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        Log.d("Height:", height + "");
        rlParent.getLayoutParams().height = height
                + rlParent.getMeasuredHeight();
        rlParent.invalidate();// Change the height of the Relative layout programatically

        // Layout params for the middle image--
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,
                RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ImageView ivMiddle = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.imagemiddle, null);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,
                RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        ivMiddle.setLayoutParams(params);
        rlParent.addView(ivMiddle, params);

    }
}
```

This is not the exact answer ; But this should help you in getting the desired output.

Comment: this might work, but thing is its not just 3 images, thr are a lot more, so this approach is not so viable

Comment: I guess the images are of the same size?